# RDP from (OSX, Android) to WIN vmware keyboard map

Tags: remote-desktop, vmware-workstation

I've seen a lot of posts regarding this issue but non answered my setup issue.
I am on a OSX laptop RDP into Win 10 machine.  When I RDP into windows everything works fine, keyboard maps correct and mouse works flawlessly.
From that Win machine I have VMware workstation 16 pro and this is where the problem begins.  My OSX keyboard is not mapped correctly on VMware, the mouse is fine.

I have switched VM setting USB to 1.1, 2.0 still no luck.
Also my VMware setting does **not** have: Virtual Machine > Settings > Keyboard & Mouse.

How can I fix this so that VMware maps remote keyboard correctly?

When I use VMware directly from windows everything works fine but its only when RDP from non windows machine (OSX, Android) the keyboard map is incorrect.